# Swap position of elements or sub-trees using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML like:

```
<root>
     <a>
       <a1>field_name**1**</a1>
       <a2>field_value**1**</a2>
     </a>
     <a>
       <a1>field_name**2**</a1>
       <a2>field_value**2**</a2>
     </a>
     <a>
       <a1>field_name**3**</a1>
       <a2>field_value**3**</a2>
     </a>
<root>
```

And I need to replace the order of the elements based on the field name like below:

```
<root>
     <a>
       <a1>field_name**2**</a1>
       <a2>field_value**2**</a2>
     </a>
     <a>
       <a1>field_name**1**</a1>
       <a2>field_value**1**</a2>
     </a>
     <a>
       <a1>field_name**3**</a1>
       <a2>field_value**3**</a2>
     </a>
<root>
```

The actual XML has a great deal more key value pairs, so it wouldn't be efficient to recreate the file completely.
What is best way to change the order of the fields using XSL?

editted with formatting

Comment: What determines the order of the `a` elements you want to have in the output? You say "based on the file name" but the sample data doesn't seem to suggest a sort or other ordering operation.

Comment: *"replace the order of the elements based on the field name"* I don't see anything based on the field name. Please explain in words the logic you want tp apply here.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. The file contains a large number of key value pairs.
Element <a> is generic to all pairs. Element <a1> contains the name of the data point, and <a2> contains the value.

The order of elements needs to be updated so that field_name***2*** appears before field_name***1***

The are a number of instances were this transformation should be applied, so i tried to make the question generic. For example, the content of a[45] should switch position with the content of a[46]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***-- edited in response to clarifications --***

To swap the contents of any pair of two adjacent `a` elements where the value of `a1` of the first `a` element is `"field_name1"`:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[a1='field_name1']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::a[1]/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[preceding-sibling::a[1]/a1='field_name1']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::a[1]/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes that the value of `a1` of the second `a` element is NOT `"field_name1"`. Otherwise the results will be ... well, a mess.

Comment: Thanks! not every even/odd pair just a few times throughout the file. For example 1+2, 45+46 112+113.
The 2 pairs will always be consecutive.
The position of 2 pairs is not consistent, some files contains 50 pairs, some files contain 500 pairs, but the content always follows the same format.
The only way to identify the pairs is by the content of <a1>

Comment: Don't tell me *"for example"*. Tell me **exactly** what the rules are.

Comment: I want to swap the content of a[a1='field_name1'] with the content of the consecutive element 'a'


Ideally in a template, so that i can pass a value for field a1 for reusability

Comment: Is that the rule? The value of of the `a1` element in the first `a` of the pair? And this value ("field_name1") can be hard-coded into the stylesheet?

Comment: yes this is the only way to identify the first item in the pair to swap